# Logic proof help

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Can someone give me a proof that,

No true claim can derive a contradiction in a consistent system of axioms,

With out using a proof by contradiction

Comment: How do you define "a consistent system of axioms"?

Comment: A list of axioms, that can't derive two contradictory statements

Comment: Okay, and what's the definition of a "true claim"? (I'm not trying to be a jerk here, just trying to ascertain what's what.)

Comment: True and false are semantic properties of sentences *in a given structure* (or a class of those). Deriving contradictions and consistency are syntactical properties.

Comment: I think OP might have meant to ask about a "constructive" proof of soundess of FOL. It's hard to imagine a constructive proof that something does not exist, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't understand what your saying could you help me out please

Comment: If you don't understand the terminology of the question that you have posted on this site, then perhaps before posting it and asking people to help you, you should review the definitions again.

Comment: Please let's remain civil, @RGB.

Answer (score 2):

There is no proof of the sort asked for in the question because the assertion to be proved isn't correct.  A consistent system of axioms may well contain a false axiom. The negation of that false axiom would be a true statement which, in the system under consideration, leads to a contradiction.

A trivial example of a consistent system of axioms containing a false axiom is the system consisting of the single axiom $2+2=5$.  As long as you don't have other axioms available to deduce the correct facts of arithmetic, $2+2=5$ is consistent.

A more reasonable but more complicated example would be to take the usual ZFC axiom system for set theory (whose consistency I take for granted) and adjoin to it the false axiom that expresses "there is a formal proof of a contradiction in ZFC" (i.e., it expresses "ZFC is inconsistent").  Despite the false axiom, this system is consistent, by Gödel's second incompleteness theorem.

Answer (score 2):

> "No true claim can derive a contradiction in a consistent system of axioms."

What does this mean? That given a consistent set of axioms as background assumptions, and presumably some logic to do some derivations with, there is no derivation that leads from a true claim to a contradiction??

But *that* is just false. Take the single axiom $P$ [if you like, "the moon is made of green cheese"] and let standard propositional logic be your derivation system. Then we have a trivially consistent set of axioms. But, equally trivially, the proposition $\neg P$ (given the background axiom) leads immediately to contradiction. Yet $\neg P$ [on the given interpretation] is true!

The point is a straightforward one: if the axioms are themselves unsound, not true on a given interpretation, then you have a theory which can lead from a true additional premiss to a false conclusion, even a necessarily false one.